# Removing duplicates from an attribute of a class variable

Tags: python, class, dictionary, attributes, key

I'm extremely new to python and was having some trouble with removing duplicate values from an attribute of a class (I think this is the correct terminology).

Specifically I want to remove every value that is the same year. I should note that I'm printing only the first four value and searching for the first four values. The data within the attribute is actually in Yearmonthday format (example: 19070101 is the year 1907 on the first on january).

Anyways, here is my code:

```
import csv
import os

class Datatype:
    'Data from the weather station'
    def __init__ (self, inputline):
        [   self.DATE,
            self.PRCP] = inputline.split(',')


filename ='LAWe.txt'
LAWd = open(filename, 'r')
LAWefile = LAWd.read()
LAWd.close()

'Recognize the line endings for MS-DOS, UNIX, and Mac and apply the .split() method to the string wholeFile'
if '\r\n' in LAWefile:
    filedat = LAWefile.split('\r\n')        # the split method, applied to a string, produces a list
elif '\r' in LAWefile:
    filedat = LAWefile.split('\r')
else:
    filedat = LAWefile.split('\n')


collection = dict()
date= dict()
for thisline in filedat:
    thispcp = Datatype(thisline)                 # here is where the Datatype object is created (running the __init__ function)
    collection[thispcp.DATE] = thispcp        # the dictionary will be keyed by the ID attribute
for thisID in collection.keys():
    studyPRP = collection[thisID]   
    if studyPRP.DATE.isdigit():
        list(studyPRP.DATE)         
        if len(date[studyPRP.DATE][0:4]):
            pass                           #if year is seen once, then skip and go to next value in attribute
        else:
            print studyPRP.DATE[0:4]        #print value in this case the year)
            date[studyPRP.DATE]=studyPRP.DATE[0:4]
```

I get a this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 61, in 
    if len(date[studyPRP.DATE][0:4]):
KeyError: '19770509'

A key error (which means a value isn't in a list? but it is for my data) can be fixed by using a set function (or so I've read), but I have 30,000 pieces of information I'm dealing with and it seems like you have to manually type in that info so that's not an option for me.

Any help at all would be appreciated

Sorry if this is confusing or nonsensical as I'm extremely new to python.

Comment: So what's `Datatype`? What's in `filedat`? Please give a [mcve], otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: I edited the code to include that info. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Note *minimal*, and give the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
if len(date[studyPRP.DATE][0:4])
```

by this

```
if len(date[studyPRP.DATE[0:4]]):
```

Explanation :

- In the first line you are selecting the whole date as the key `KeyError: '19770509'` in the 4 first entry of date
- In the correction you send the the first 4 character of the date(the year) in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly you want here. I'll reply based on I can help you on what.

Your error is because you are accessing your year in `data` before you are adding it.

Also, what you are adding to your collection is like

```
{
    <object>.DATE: <object>
}
```

I don't know what you need here. Your lower `for loop` can be written as under:

```
for thisID in collection:
    if thisID.isdigit():
        if thisID[0:4] in date and len(date[thisID[0:4]]):
            #if year is seen once, then skip and go to next 
            # value in attribute
            pass
        else:
            print thisID[0:4]        #print value in this case the year)
            date[thisID[0:4]]=thisID[0:4]
```

Note your `studyPRP.DATE` is same as `thisID`.